Request to make closing questions regarding very recent malfunctions in space a valid vote-to-close reason
Skeptics SE has recent events as a community-specific reason to close:

Questions about unresolved current events and issues currently under investigation by a court of law, government, or other similar investigative body are off-topic because there is insufficient data for a meaningful answer. For more information, see Handling current news questions.

This certainly applies here. Space exploration is rather hostile, and problems do happen, with greater frequency than desirable. One issue is that getting to a root cause can take months and sometimes years (and sometimes forever). Another contrary issue is that whenever there is a malfunction in space with deleterious effects, people get curious and ask us here. Those members who might have inside information are typically forbidden from answering by employment agreements and NDAs. Everyone else is armchair quarterbacking.
So simply close them as unresolved current events.

I’m of two minds about this. (1) I am sometimes annoyed by [space event happening] immediately followed by someone running here with a “what happened?” question when there’s simply no public information about it. (2) how long is “long enough” before asking about an event, and (2a) if the answer is “once info is available”, then the requirement to ask a question about a mishap would more or less be to also already know the answer which feels overly strict.

This really has to be more closely defined. I disagree that all questions about a recent events are unanswerable. There is a big difference between asking if- or why something went wrong. The former being answerable, while the latter needs to wait. If a company pre-planned to trigger the FTS on a lower stage to help it break up during reentry and a user asks about a visible explosion, regardless if any other issues arose on the flight, that should be on-topic since it is answerable.

@fyrepenguin I, too, get annoyed by such questions. Something along the lines of "Questions about specific details regarding unresolved current events and issues currently under investigation ... are off-topic." However, questions motivated by some current event, but not asking specifically about that event, might well be on-topic.

There could be a downside to adopting this rule: The site might stagnate. (It already appears to be stagnating as most of the good questions have already been asked.) This stagnation definitely happened with the Earth Science SE when they banned "identify this rock" questions. We now get a lot fewer questions at the site. But at least they're not the annoying "identify this rock!" with a very vague description of the rock in question.

@TheRocketfan The proposal does not apply to all recent events. It applies only to questions asking us about inherently unresolved recent events. "Did something just happen to MyFavoriteSatellite? It appears to have gone offline!" That's answerable. "What just happened to MyFavoriteSatellite?" is often going to require an inquiry board that will have access to inside information; we as a community do not have such access. (Those members who do have such access typically are not allowed to release it lest they be fired.) Those are the questions I want to be able to close immediately.

@TheRocketfan There are also questions motivated by recent events but that skirt around asking about that recent event: "MyFavoriteSatellite apparently just exploded after seven years in orbit. I'm not asking about MyFavoriteSatellite. I'm asking generically what can cause a satellite to explode after such a long time in service?" That's a bit of a list question, but it is answerable.

@DavidHammen Is there any chance you'll add some links to at least a few actual, concrete examples of questions you propose need to, and could be closed by this new rule?

I think the principle should be to judge the answer, not the question. if the answer is evidence-based, keep it. If it is opinion based and speculative, then feel free to delete it. It is counterproductive to delete an interesting question for fear it may... whaaaat?

Consider a post notice, like the "rapidly changing events" notice, except exactly the opposite.
Per @ErinAnne's suggestion I'll break out my comment into a new answer.
So far I think we have a very small, but nonzero number of users complaining about a very small, but nonzero number of questions, that have yet to be specifically identified (i.e. no specific examples) and no specific, demonstrable harm that can be unambiguously pointed to.
I think that creating a brand new, site-specific close reason (like the one about blowing oneself up with DIY rocket fuel in one's garage) is far away from being justified.
And I'm pretty sure that from time-to-time these questions DO get answered years later. Someone vaguely remembers an old question when some news item comes out, finds it, and drops in an answer.
If the question is closed, that's really a disincentive to answering because you have to manually start the reopen process, then wait, and hope that it takes. I think that Stack Exchange handles reopens triggered by an edit to the question differently than those triggered by someone just clicking "reopen" and then leaving a nearly invisible message at the bottom of the comment list saying "hey, please vote to reopen because I have an answer".
So since there is a vague feeling that something should be done, but a hard close of an otherwise good question seems counterproductive, consider a post notice. Something like:

At the time of the asking this may not be immediately answerable. Please don't post speculation answers, but if at a later date more info is available, you are welcome to post an answer or an update with your new information.


I think the proposal is not yet ripe.
When it comes to proposing changes to sites, policies, norms, etc., Stack Exchange canon requires us to do some things:

demonstrate recognizable harm to the site, community or individual users by the status quo
explain why the proposed change mitigates that harm
address how the change would not likely cause new, collateral, unintended harm

If Skeptics SE is to be the model for the proposed change, one might first explain what the harm was there that lead to the creation of the special close reason, and examine if the same harm is actually occurring here.
Personally I think Skeptics SE and Space SE are Astronomical Units apart in terms of how they work and how answers are evaluated and appreciated. I don't think that community is a good model for this one.
Just because some users don't like certain specific kinds questions, that's not reason enough to ban them for everyone.
I think each time DH has complained in comments under a question about this, there's been pushback by others in comments. We might collect those and examine if there is really an argument to be made that stands up.
Personally, I am just not seeing harm from reasonably well-written/researched and on-topic questions that many feel can't be answered right now. I'm open to being convinced of it, if it can be articulated.
In the absence of demonstrable harm, we should stick with "If it's not broke, don't fix it" precisely because the "fix" might do harm.


I think we have an obvious harm that comes from these questions - a lot of frustration that often leads to argument, new visitors getting the impression that asking questions is not going to get answers, and an overall negative outcome. 2) putting a question on hold quickly before this happens with a standard placeholder saying "wait" takes that painful period away. 3) any harm from a polite "wait" with a boilerplate reason is going to be less than the stuff we usually have to wade through to ease frustrations and calm arguments.


I completely agree with @RoryAlsop on this. If I didn't agree I would not have posed the question.

I do see the downside. As I mentioned in a comment under my question, look at what happened to Earth Science SE after they decided to ban rock identification questions. Those questions were far too often unanswerable due to the typically vague description of the rock in question (and where the rock was found), and  far too often very annoying. Traffic at the site went down as a consequence of that rule. But at least the questions that remain are interesting.

@DavidHammen that was directly related to quality of the questions. It was not that the question type itself was unanswerable - the good ones got answered quite regularly. It was the high rate of poor, low quality and frequently abandoned questions in that category, where the OPs would not respond to requests for additional information. That was profoundly obvious there - there were hundreds, they clogged up the review queue. If you can demonstrate that there is a high rate of low quality questions here, then the Earth Science analogy makes sense.

I suspect you would be hard-pressed to come up with a dozen low quality questions that also ask about things that can't be immediately answered. If you want to do this the normal way, list at least a half-dozen specific questions in your post that caused harm, and the site would be better had they been quickly closed because they could not be answered immediately. Let's see some compelling data!

@DavidHammen cf. Rock ID in Earth Science SE: The high flux of low quality questions has put the community under stress... I'm just not seeing that happening here in Space SE due to the quite infrequent type of question you are talking about. Apples and oranges.

@uhoh I certainly am seeing exactly that happening here in Space.SE. Rory also sees it. To me, those "what just happened to X???" questions typically are low quality questions, and they are far too often unanswerable. By the time such questions are answerable they have been answered elsewhere.

Ex: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/66440/ https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/52072/ https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49080/ https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/66532/ https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/67064/ come to mind. Admittedly, they’re all positively scored, IIRC, and I don’t know if they count as “caused harm”. I do feel like it’s a kind of easy way to farm rep - look at a space newsfeed, see mishap, ask question, receive no answer because no one has information (but the question isn’t bad, you see, so it gets upvoted). Whether that’s a problem

@fyrepenguin https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/67064/ this question shouldn’t be considered under that category because it is not asking "why" a malfunction happened, but "if". - Big difference

@fyrepenguin "Admittedly, they’re all positively scored..." So actually you've made the counter-argument! The community does not seem to have any problem with one well-received question per year along these lines.

@RoryAlsop are there examples of "a lot of frustration that often leads to argument" we could review? That would help us to understand if this is widespread sentiment, or perhaps all coming from a single user which is what I suspect is happening. I'd like to know the number of users who have serious complaints about these rare occurenes, and if that number is significantly larger than one. Links to these arguments would help, as would links to more than one question/year

@RoryAlsop that's why I point out in my answer that any request should include a convincing body of examples of actual harm. Without examples cited in the question for the community review, DH's complaint is not yet ripe for consideration. As a counterexample, DH actually posted a +10 answer to the +10 question he most recently complained about.

@RoryAlsop for example, the discussion below this DH non-answer went on a long time, but I agree with this comment which seems to have stopped DH's complaints quickly. "There are examples of questions that have been sitting there, and then been answered two years later when the report came out." Are here non-DH-initiated arguments I'm not aware of?

I had a whole thing written (left below the horizontal rule) but then I felt surprised about Rory Alsop's comment.
My surprise is--and maybe this is wandering too far astray:  does a question being VTC'd really help with the things that Rory indicates?
My impression was that the intent of a VTC is to prevent a question being answered, typically to allow a question time to be edited so that it's clear what's being asked, or to prevent answers to an off-topic question.
But for example Why traveling to the international space station can't be done with airplanes? seems like a perfectly typical example of a VTC on Space Exploration SE:  it got answers because we actually don't close quickly here (I think it sat on 4 close votes for a day? I didn't vote to close, because I thought it was perfectly clear, just not useful and poorly researched, which is a downvote for me not a VTC), the answers aren't actually the part that we object to, but now it's closed and...what?  We've had the fights we're going to have, probably, unless we get argued at for closing it too like happens.
I actually think we might not have enough active high-rep users for a Vote-to-Close to give us the advantages we act like it will.
Instead, I think it'll take a day to VTC one of these questions, we'll still get the armchair quarterback answers and the arguments, ESPECIALLY if it gets Hot Network Question status, and at the point the question becomes answerable it'll take another day to re-open the old question. Or the answer goes in a duplicate (which I guess isn't bad, since we don't value the answers to the old question at this point).
I dunno, maybe I'm just foolish on this. I certainly don't spend much time on any of the other network sites.

the thing I'd written before:
I'd like to make a case against, though in many aspects I agree with what you're saying.  I might actually start with what I agree with you on.
Way too many answers we get here are already poorly-researched and poorly-supported
This applies to all questions, but I think you're also right that questions about news items will tend to attract more of that opinion and speculation that leads to low-quality answers.
(Mea culpa: my post history probably contains some of those answers.  I have been very flippant with them sometimes.)
All that's already supposed to be discouraged by the site mechanics, but if we aren't kidding ourselves I think we see it's not?  Especially if it becomes a Hot Network Question and shows up on the front page, upvotes fly for virtually any set of words. P
That said,
If we don't answer a question for a while, that's fine
This is technically outside the scope of this meta, since you specifically mention recent malfunctions in the title, but I think my question What are the technical differences between AxEMU and xEMU? hits a lot of the same bases. The answers might remain trade secrets and just get lost like so much engineering information does.  But like I said at the end of the question--sometimes you come across something and you may as well ask. And where else?
What questions DO we want to answer, then?
I think this community is still pretty picky, and I'm among the picky ones.  But are we really going to further-limit what's on topic until there's information sufficient to answer the question?  Probably not (is the questioner really expected to know that?), so how long are people supposed to wait to ask?  Until it's not a current news story?  Are people supposed to VTC if they don't think there's public information to answer with yet?
Personally I'd take a thousand "why did [thing in the news] happen" questions over the "is [my not-even-napkin-sketch idea] [awesome]? why?"
I see that in the time I've waited before posting this (because I wrote it late at night) DH has brought up a concern about site stagnation.  I agree with that. It sounds like the Earth Science SE change helped there, though?

re: the Earth Science analogy is not even close to a valid analogy.

Please don't. Some questions can't be immediately answered, that's fine. How is the asker supposed to know if their question has an a findable answer if they don't know the answer themselves (or else they wouldn't ask/would self-answer)? That's an unreasonable standard.
Go to the Unanswered section. The questions there, no has been able to answer, some for years. Should we close them all? No, of course not. Plenty of questions hang in that section for years and were then answered, sometimes by something that didn't exist when the question was originally asked. But becuase they remained open they were eventually answered. Questions about recent malfunctions, if not immediately answerable, may be answerable in a week, and why should we prevent a good answer that could come after a week or make people go through the trouble or closing and reopening it?
Besides, what harm do these questions do? To justify the effort of closing/reopening them, the "harm" of not being able to answer it for a short period of time, which simply means the question will take a while to get answered, hardly seems sufficient.

As far as StackOverflow/StackExchange management is concerned, there are lots of problems with sites that have (in their eyes) too many unanswered questions. That said, there are lots of issues with regard to StackOverflow/StackExchange management as far as ordinary users and especially volunteer workers (who work for free) are concerned. Lots and lots and lots of issues. Open disclosure: I am not StackOverflow/StackExchange management.

@DavidHammen again, no examples. How can we distinguish your assertions from "They're eating the dogs... They're eating the cats..." if you never point to specific examples?

@uhoh I think pointing to actual misinformation, not something that people just think is misinformation would help your arguement a bit:)

@Starship "All proceeds from this song will be donated to Clark County SPCA in Springfield, Ohio" Keep it light.

I decided to go back through as many questions as I could to see the scale of the issue, and while I may have over-stressed the problem, there is definitely a challenge with how we deal with these sorts of questions.
I don't think there is a problem with the questions as such, but having them open when there is no way to answer until information becomes public does lead to some negative behaviours:

Speculative answers being posted - which leads to downvotes, arguments and deletions, and the usual challenges when asking for citations.
New Askers getting annoyed with the site's inability to answer "simple questions"
New Askers "rep farming"
These types of questions can easily end up on the Hot Questions list, because ... algorithms

And of course open questions that linger for quite some time can give a negative impression of the site (I don't think this is necessarily an issue)
My feeling from seeing posts like this on all the sites I moderate is that closing them quickly with a very clear message that it is just to await information being available tends to land better than leaving open. I'm pretty supportive of using "putting on hold" rather than "closing" in situations like this, to help indicate the temporary nature of it.
I agree with Erin that there are too many low quality posts here, but I don't think these questions about recent events should be in that category (although some might be)

Does stack exchange really have a "put on hold" status that is separate from, and works differently than closing? It sounds like euphemisation to me - "let's not call your closed question closed, let's just say we've 'put it on hold' for you, for now" would feel patronizing to me. Unless there's something functionally different between a "hold" and a "close", we shouldn't invent separate terms. Closed is closed.

In the system it is "closed" but we can always reopen, so to me the aim is usually to put them on hold until edits fix issues, and then open them up again. Closed sounds very permanent, which is often not the aim.

There is a trigger mechanism - when edits are made, there's an option to move the question to the review queue. There is no such mechanism where AI detects when more information is available and automatically moves the question to review or starts a reopen. Closed questions are probably more likely to be forgotten, and the OP may not know there is more information and then initiate the reopen process themselves. If the question is just dormant, anybody can just write an answer if they happen to remember there was a question.

Why make them go through the 24/48 hour wait period  hoping for five people to reopen it? How will they know that someone has new information? There's been no edit, the post isn't updated, there may be a comment way at the bottom saying "I have an answer!" but queue-reviewers may not take the time to scroll to the last comment. The "hold until edits fix issues" applies to the question post. That's unrelated to new information becoming available. There's no such thing as a "hold until more information is available". We don't have the mechanics for such a thing.
